# how to prove: if $uv=x^p$ then $a^{p-i}u=(ar)^p$ and $a^iv=(as)^p$?

Tags: number-theory

Are the following proposition and proof correct:

Let $u,v$ be integers. If $uv=x^p$ with $x\in\mathbb Z$, then there are integers $a,r,s, i$ such
$$a^{p-i}u=(ar)^p$$
$$a^iv=(as)^p$$
with $\gcd(r,s)=1$ and $i\ge 0$.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

What I have done:

Proof:

Let $x=ars$ with $a,r,s \in\mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(r,s)=1$.
Then
$$uv=(ars)^p=a^{p-i+i}r^p s^p$$
Hence
$$u=a^ir^p$$
$$v=a^{p-i}s^p$$

Hence
$$a^{p-i}u=(ar)^p$$
$$a^iv=(as)^p$$
$\square.$

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: One of your hypothesis is that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, but there is no $b$ in the problem. Maybe you meant $\gcd(u,v)=1$?

Comment: No. I meant $\gcd(r,s)=1$.

Comment: Your proposition and proof don't appear to match. The proposition indicates that $u$ and $v$ may be *any* integers where $uv=x^p$, but your proof has them be of a specific form. Note that, with my understanding of your current wording, a counter-example is $u=2\times 3^2$ and $v=2\times 3^2$ giving $uv=(2\times 3)^3$. If your proposition was meant to be something like showing that there exists such integers $u$ and $v$ instead, then it, and your proof, would be correct.

Comment: $uv =(2X 3^2)^2\ne(2X3)^3$. Thanks for your input but i don't understand your counterexample. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my comment with a counter-example. It should be $v = 2^2\times 3$ instead. Then $uv = (2\times 3)^3$, i.e., with $x=2\times 3$ and $p = 3$. This requires that $r = s = 1$, but then there are no integers $a$ and $i$ where $u=2\times 3^2=a^i$ and $v=2^2\times 3=a^{p-i}$. On a separate issue, you didn't include "@" with my name, so I didn't get pinged and, instead, only noticed your response when checking back.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, Thanks for pointing this out. I see where I went wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider answering your own question specifically explaining what you now see, i.e., where you went wrong.